# Omniture Raw Log Field Names

Tags: adobe-analytics

I have a several million rows of raw Omniture logs, and I'm looking for the secret decoder ring for the 178 or so fields. The data have no field headers, so I was wondering where that mapping might be documented.

Sample row:

```
1331799426  2012-03-15 01:17:06 2860005755985467733 4611687631188657821 FAS-2.8-AS3 N   0   99.122.210.248  1   0       10  http://www.acme.com/SH55126545/VD55170364   {7AAB8415-E803-3C5D-7100-E362D7F67CA7}                                                  U   en-us,en;q=0.5      516 575 1366    Y   N   Y   2   0   304 sbcglobal.net   15/2/2012 4:16:0 4 240  45  41  10002,00011,10020,00007 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6    48  0   2   3   0   homestead   usa 528 fl  0   0   0   0                               0                                                                   WPLG                    0                                           120                                                                                             WPLG                                                                                                                                                                                                            0
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is called a Clickstream Datafeed. I am not clear exactly on the ordering, maybe the first 4 columns have been removed from your example. But the columns are defined here.
https://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/clickstream/index.html#Clickstream_Data_Column_Reference

Thanks C.

Comment: Adobe has a master list of all possible columns, as described in your link. But when you setup a datafeed, you select which columns you want the datafeed to be for, so a given datafeed may or may not have all available columns. So basically, that link is useful as a reference for what expected values are for a given column, but you really have to have a mapping of the datafeed itself before you can begin

Comment: Here is the updated link https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/clickstream/datafeeds_reference.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of lookup table files that are created at the same time as the clickstream.  The file column_headers.tsv are the column headers that are associated with hit_data.tsv